# QL -Two columns need to displayed together in one column head

Tags: sql

I have a complex Database which includes Invoice Table, Collection Table, Employee Table

Invoice(id, date, amount, employeeid) 
Collection(id, invoiceid, date, amount) 
Employee(id, name, address)

I want to have an output which will display employee name, (Net Sales , Net Collection)-2columns displayed under one head together in one column-Jan 2013

I want to columnspan Jan 2013 to have two fields-Net Sales, Net Collection--- the output will be generated with the SQL DATABASE with a query...

I want to know what query should I have to write to display EMPLOYEE NAME JAN2013 Encapsulating (NET SALES, NeTCollection)

Please have a look at the image what I am actually trying to create

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8VaB.png)

Comment: SQL is a language to query the data not a presentation tool. So do all the columnspans and everything in your presentation layer. Now post sample data and desired output based on it that will allow you to do your presentation correct and we will try to help. It'll be great if you also show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Put the Sample what you have tried till yet.

Comment: Also when you post a question asking for help with a query **always** specify (as a tag) what RDBMS (SQL Server, MySql, Oracle ...) you are using and preferably a version, because there lots of vendor specifics .

Comment: I have tried it and I am unable specifically ask or show what I desire...May be its a presentation thing...I wish I had the option to display actually what I want as an output.....

Comment: If you want to be helped can you specifically post sample data in a tabular form and desired output like in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17059881/1920232? If you can't do that nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: where you will display this data web page some report tool. You need to handle it on presentation layer

Answer (score 0):

You are required to add the result using + and then  saving the same in  the alias of the columns:

Like :

EmpName+ convert(nvarchar, net sales )+ convert (nvarchar, net collection ) as 'new column'

Comment: I wish I had the option to show an image of what I actually desire...its been a week I am trying to get an answer to my question and every time I found my post closed by the administrators....

Comment: If we totally forget about sql...n think like an excel document where a table shows name of the employees and their sales and collection of each month...by which I mean a column employeee name, a column Jan 2013 spanning two columns Net Sales, Net Collection....please think like an excel file

Answer (score 0):

you haven't mentioned about your db. I am assuming SQL Server.
You may need to use Pivot query sample pivot query is below

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        year(invoiceDate) as [year],left(datename(month,invoicedate),3)as [month], 
        InvoiceAmount as Amount 
    FROM Invoice
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
    may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS pivot
```

I have taken the excerpt from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query) you may study the link to understand it in detail. In your case year would be employee. Column spanning would be handle on presentation

Comment: I want to display the Sales and Collection together..please look at the link http://i.imgur.com/rso2ItJ.png

Comment: I think in above comments everyone has told you clearly in sql it is not possible you need to handle it in PRESENTATION LAYER. and should be easy to do that. in pivot create two column for every month one for collection one for sale and combine them on view