# PostgreSQL, calculating ingredients from normatives

Tags: postgresql

Before some time i get here very reliable query for [calculating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030422/postgresql-mixed-food-and-recipes) ingredients from normatives but with time I get need for advancing a bit.

Here are example tables:

```
CREATE TABLE myusedfood 
       (mybill int, mydate text, food_code int, food_name text, qtyu integer, meas text); 
INSERT INTO myusedfood (mybill, mydate, food_code, food_name, qtyu, meas)
VALUES (1,  '03.01.2014', 10,   'spaghetti',        3,   'pcs'),
       (2,  '04.01.2014', 156,  'mayonnaise',       2,   'pcs'),
       (3,  '06.01.2014', 173,  'ketchup',          1,   'pcs'),
       (4,  '07.01.2014', 172,  'bolognese sauce',  2,   'pcs'),
       (5,  '08.01.2014', 173,  'ketchup',          1,   'pcs'),
       (6,  '15.01.2014', 175,  'worchester sauce', 2,   'pcs'),
       (7,  '16.01.2014', 177,  'parmesan',         1,   'pcs'),
       (8,  '17.01.2014', 10,   'spaghetti',        2,   'pcs'),
       (9,  '18.01.2014', 156,  'mayonnaise',       1,   'pcs'),
       (10, '19.01.2014', 10,   'spaghetti',        2,   'pcs'),
       (11, '19.01.2014', 1256, 'spaghetti rinf',   100, 'gramm'),
       (12, '20.01.2014', 156,  'mayonnaise',       2,   'pcs'),
       (13, '21.01.2014', 173,  'ketchup',          1,   'pcs'),
       (14, '19.01.2014', 10,   'spaghetti',        2,   'pcs');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myingredients;
CREATE TABLE myingredients
      (food_code int, ingr_code int, ingr_name text, qtyi decimal(10, 3), meas text);
INSERT INTO myingredients (food_code, ingr_code, ingr_name, qtyi, meas)
VALUES (10,  1256, 'spaghetti rinf', 75, 'gramm'),
       (156, 1144, 'salt',          0.3, 'gramm'),
       (10,  1144, 'salt',          0.5, 'gramm'),
       (156, 1140, 'fresh egg',      50, 'gramm'),
       (172, 1138, 'tomato',         80, 'gramm'),
       (156, 1139, 'mustard',         5, 'gramm'),
       (172, 1136, 'clove',           1, 'gramm'),
       (156, 1258, 'oil',           120, 'gramm'),
       (172, 1135, 'laurel',        0.4, 'gramm'),
       (10,  1258, 'oil',           0.4, 'gramm'),
       (172, 1130, 'corned beef',    40, 'gramm');
```

First table contains bill's number and date, notmative's/ingredient's code, name, selled quantity.
Second represent normative's code, ingredient's code, ingredient's name, ingredient's quantity in related normative.

With this query I get listed all ingredients from all normatives plus normatives which haven't any ingredients. That work OK.

```
SELECT SUM(f.qtyu)                        AS used,
       COALESCE(i.ingr_code, f.food_code) AS code,
       COALESCE(i.ingr_name, f.food_name) AS f_name,
       SUM(COALESCE(i.qtyi, 1) * f.qtyu)  AS qty,
       COALESCE(i.meas, f.meas)           AS meas
  FROM myusedfood f LEFT JOIN myingredients i
    ON f.food_code = i.food_code 
 GROUP BY COALESCE(i.ingr_code, f.food_code), 
       COALESCE(i.ingr_name, f.food_name),
       COALESCE(i.meas, f.meas)
 ORDER BY code;
```

With time my real tables becames huge and queries slower. I often need to get results for just one food code but I don't know how to do that properly regarding of speed.
For example with showed tables if we query for ingredient code 1256 result should be

```
  used ing.code    ing.name       qty      meas
------------------------------------------------------
   109,  1256, "spaghetti rinf", 775.000, "gramm"
```

Where article 1256 is "used" 9 times in normative (10) and 100g :) as alone, all in qty of 775 gramms.

Here I have 2 questions:
How to optimize upper query to list only one code instead of all, say code 1256?
How to get list of all records related to code 1256.

Result should look like this:

```
bill       date     code      name             qty
------------------------------------------------------
   1,  '03.01.2014', 10,   'spaghetti',        225
   8,  '17.01.2014', 10,   'spaghetti',        150
  10,  '19.01.2014', 10,   'spaghetti',        150
  11,  '19.01.2014', 1256, 'spaghetti rinf',   100
  14,  '19.01.2014', 10,   'spaghetti',        150
------------------------------------------------------
                                               775
```

Note that ingredient 1256 may be selled in normative (10) or alone as is.

Please help to get those two needed queries.

Comment: I don't understand the structure of your tables.  Why is there no primary key?  Also what is a "normative"?

Comment: As far as speed is concerned, your design is a little lacking in terms of optimization. At a minimum, I hope you're indexing your join columns